# Moving PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, location, coordinates, picturebox

> Could someone help me?
> I really don't know what to do. I don't want to restart my project even if there is little code inside it don't ask me why. Maybe because Im lazy. I think it is probably problems with the varibels I guess. As I said I don't know.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_Zomboid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int positiony = 0; 
        int positionx = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            player.Controls.Add(ak47gun);
            ak47gun.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            ak47gun.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            Startup();
            player.Location = new Point(positionx, positiony);
        }
    
    void Startup()
        {
        if (true == true)
            {
 
            }
            
        }
                 
    private void keypress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W) 
            {
                positiony += 1;
            }
        
            else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S) 
            {
                positiony -= 1;
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) 
            {
                positionx += 1;
            }

            else if( e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                positionx -= 1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_Zomboid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int positiony = 0; 
        int positionx = 0;
        Thread gameLoop;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            player.Controls.Add(ak47gun);
            ak47gun.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            ak47gun.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            gameLoop = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Startup));
            gameLoop.Start();
        }
    
    public void Startup()
    {
        while(true)
        {
             player.Location = new Point(positionx, positiony);
             Thread.Sleep(128);
        }   
    }
                 
    private void keypress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W) 
            {
                positiony += 1;
            }
        
            else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S) 
            {
                positiony -= 1;
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) 
            {
                positionx += 1;
            }

            else if( e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                positionx -= 1;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I think that will get your image moving around the screen but, I would seriously suggest if you're interested in making games you should consider watching a lot of tutorials online on youtube. This movement isn't time sensitive so your picture will move as fast as the cpu can add to the x or y position. Which should be really fast. The sleep in the thread is to make sure your picture isn't always updating. I would first suggest a tutorial that explains delta time and velocity.

There are also a TON of free example games online that can give you a great example of how a lot of this is done.

Something else to note is if you don't want a game loop/thread update the player.Location = new Point(positionx, positiony) inside the keypress method after updating the integer.